# Excel - A row in my Pivot table calculates sum wrongly only for some entries (same data type/format)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-columns

I created a tracker of learning hours in order to conduct an experiment.
For the purpose of the ticket, there is a time series that does not sum correctly data in Pivot table.

Some other tickets on Stack Overflow mention how to correctly sum. Here's what I tried:

- considered blank spaces > the Pivot does not consider them anymore, yet the issue persist.
- data type & format > the whole column is set for data type *short date*
- labeling > I use to copy-paste the category for each learning and I double checked if there was no typo in them.

**Here's how the file works.** There are 3 sheet in my Excel file. The core of it is "Data" where I do track the time spent for each learning / exercise. The columns marked in red are the ones used for the next Pivot Table.
[image: Data - Sheet]

These information are consolidated in another sheet, called **SuperLearner Review**. I use this one to display overall learning hours by type and category. Numeric outputs here are looked up from Data (or calculated accordingly).
[image: Learning Review - Consolidation Sheet]

After several checks, I cannot retrieve the issue. All I know is that for February data are not tracked correctly.
Originally I attributed either to wrong data labeling or format, but I can manually see what is the real sum of learning done in February:
[image: Learning Hours in February]

In the data-series those hours seem not to display. This is what the Pivot table returns instead:
[image: Pivot Table - Time Series]

Whereas, for the consolidated information (coming from the same source) does not seem there are problems in calculation:

[image: Pivot Table - By Category]

When I tried to cancel and build up again the same Pivot Table, the same error occur. So I am not getting out of this wrong calculation. Therefore it must not be a problem of calculation, rather than Excel does not retrieve some data entries at one point.
What would you recommend? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since your `time` may be > 24 hours, format those cells as `[hh]:mm:ss`  to prevent the hours from "rolling over" every 24. There may still be an error, because I would have expected February to be `25:57:00` and not `26:57:00`

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue!